# How to update DevExpress CollectionView row in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, devexpress

I'm developing a xamarin forms app. I want user select some values and then update collectionview after that to show selected value on that row.
That 2 is selected value.It comes here but sometimes falls to error that *'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'*

[image]

**C# Code**

```
ObservableCollection<DynamicReportsParameters> reportsParameters;
public ObservableCollection<DynamicReportsParameters> ReportsParameters
    {
        get
        {
            if (reportsParameters == null)
                ReportsParameters = new ObservableCollection<DynamicReportsParameters>();
            return reportsParameters;
        }
        set => reportsParameters = value;
    } 

void fun () {
                       int ix = 0;

                       if (veri1List[i] != "0")
                        {
                            ix = Int32.Parse(veri1List[i]);
                            
                        }

                            


                        if (ReportsParameters[ix] != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("veri2 list 0 :" + veri2List[0]);
                            Console.WriteLine("ix :" + ix);



                            DynamicReportsParameters dnp = new DynamicReportsParameters()
                            {
                                ACIKLAMA = ReportsParameters[ix].ACIKLAMA,
                                ACIKLAMA2 = veri2List[0],
                                KODID = ReportsParameters[ix].KODID,
                                ORJVALUE = ReportsParameters[ix].ORJVALUE,
                                PID = ReportsParameters[ix].PID,
                                SECIM = ReportsParameters[ix].SECIM,
                                TYPE = ReportsParameters[ix].TYPE,
                                VIEW_QUERY = ReportsParameters[ix].VIEW_QUERY,
                                VNUMBER = ReportsParameters[ix].VNUMBER,
                            };



                            ReportsParameters.Insert(ix, dnp);
                            ReportsParameters.RemoveAt(ix + 1);

                            //Console.WriteLine("AÇIKLAMA :" + ReportsParameters[ix].ACIKLAMA);
                            //ReportsParameters[ix].ACIKLAMA = "MERT";
                            //Console.WriteLine("AÇIKLAMA :" + ReportsParameters[ix].ACIKLAMA);

                            OnPropertyChanged(); 
}
```

**XAML Code**

```
<dxcv:DXCollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ReportsParameters, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               SelectionMode="Single"
                               Margin="8, 2, 8, 2"
                               VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                               TapCommand="{Binding QueryPageOpenCommand}"
                               
                               SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedReportsParameters}"
                       >
            <dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10, 8, 18, 8">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>-->
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <!--<RowDefinition/>-->

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="{Binding ACIKLAMA}"
                                   FontSize="Medium"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Margin="0,2"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>

                        <Label Text="{Binding ACIKLAMA2}"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               TextColor="Black" />

                        <Image Source="@drawable/touch.png" HeightRequest="20" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </dxcv:DXCollectionView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official document about the [DXCollectionView](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.CollectionView.DXCollectionView#select-items) said:

> SelectionMode = Single
>
> When a user selects (taps) an item, the SelectedItem property is set to an object that specifies the item from the data source that corresponds to the item selected in the list. When a user taps the selected item again, the selection is cleared and the SelectedItem property is set to null.
> To select an item programmatically, assign the data source’s item object to the view model’s property and bind the SelectedItem property to it.

So you should change the `SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedReportsParameters}"` to `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReportsParameters}"` or change the `SelectionMode="Single"` to `SelectionMode = Multiple`.

In addition, you can add the `Mode=TwoWay` for the selecteditem binding.

**Update:**

Use the `int value = int.Parse(index)` can convert the index in the preferences to int directly.

Comment: That is not what I desire. I open a popup page to select items, after select popup close then this dxCollectionview update. Thank you for fast answer by the way.

Comment: But accoding to the error message, the error is caused by the collectionview. And you met problem at which step? Open popup or update dxCollectionview? @MertAltiparmak

Comment: My problem occurs updating collecitonview. As I said it works good but sometimes Im facing that error. My mind confused a lot.

Comment: But you can't use the Single SelectionMode and the SelectenItems at the same time. The SelectedItems is used for the Multiple SelectionMode and the SelectedItem is used for the Single SelectionMode. @MertAltiparmak

Comment: Okey. Im going to delete SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedReportsParameters}". I'll try my app. Maybe Collectionview's mind also confused cuz this.   
@Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: You can just change the selectionmode from single to multiple. @MertAltiparmak

Comment: Why ? I'm just using collectionview to show parameters. I select items from popup page. Then I want to update collectionview with my selected value. When my collectionview updates give me error. That's my problem now.

Comment: You can try to debug to check which line caused this error.  @MertAltiparmak

Comment: I am but my mind confused a lot. There are 2 items in my collectionview, index comes 0 but converting string to integer that 0 become 1. Than my app falls.

Comment: When you debug you can check the observable coleection's counts and index to detect why did the error appear. @MertAltiparmak

Comment: I take index with preferences. When index comes 0 app can not convert or parse it to right number. String 0 ("0") become 1. Then I write some if statements, when index is 0 I dont convert, when index is different 0 I convert. It looks fixed but not a wise way  I think. :D @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Did you mean converting string "0" to int "0"? You can use `int value = int.Parse(index)`. @MertAltiparmak

Comment: This looks good now with this : int value = int.Parse(index). If you update your answer I'll give you points. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: You are welcome. And I have updated it. @MertAltiparmak